# Manage nameservers in azure

Tags: azure, dns, cross-domain, azure-web-app-service, web-hosting

First I created a azure web app `dealkar.azurewebsites.net`. Then to use my custom domain `dealkar.pk` I go to `Custom domains and SSL` and there I bring external domain by following all the steps. Now When I go to `Custom domains and SSL`, `Host names assigned to site` contains `dealkar.pk`. It means I have successfully verified my domain 'dealkar.pk'. Right?

Before using azure, my website was hosted by godaddy. But after verifying my external domain, dealkar.pk still accesses godaddy contents. Why its not showing the contents of azure.i.e, `dealkar.azurewebsites.net`?

**Note:** Now when I open my web app in azure portal, `http://dealkar.pk` is written under `URL`.

Then I tried another option. I go to `azure portal > New > Networking > DNS Zone` then created a DNS zone. It gave me 4 nameservers. I updated nameservers against my domain dealkar.pk.

Now when I open my website, it says:

> dealkar.pk’s server DNS address could not be found

Are these nameservers provided by Azure DNS Zone are not ready for use. Why its not working?

Comment: tell me if my question is not clear or what else I should mention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're missing an important step here. What you need to do is go back to GoDaddy's (I'm assuming that you registered your domain there) DNS Zone manager and change records (CNAME, A etc.) appropriately so that they can point to the website hosted in Azure instead of pointing to the website hosted with GoDaddy. Please see this link regarding how you can do it: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/.

When you create a DNS zone in Azure and change DNS Servers in your domain registrar, you would need to create same set of records in Azure DNS as well. Because you didn't create any records in there, I believe that's the reason your name resolution is failing when you changed the nameservers.

Comment: Firstly, my domain registrar is a pakistani company and they says that for `pk` domains you can only update nameservers. That' why I created nameservers in azure. How to create set of records in Azure DNS?

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/dns-getstarted-create-recordset-portal/ in this link where ip address came from??

Comment: For a moment, let's forget Azure DNS. Change your Nameservers back to the original one in your domain registrar DNS console. Then try the steps outlined in the link I posted in my answer with your domain registrar. Your site should point to Azure after some time.

Comment: The nameservers I was using was provided by godaddy not by domain registrar. Now when I will stop using godaddy hosting why they will let me use their nameserves?

Comment: I would recommend reaching out to your domain registrar and ask them how to change the nameservers. In my case, my domains are registered with GoDaddy but my websites are hosted in Azure and yet I can still use their Nameservers. HTH.

Comment: ok! I have changed nameservers against `dealkar.pk` to the one provided by godaddy. And in Manage domain I added `cname` with Host = `awverify.dealkar.pk` and points to = `awverify.dealkar1.azurewebsites.net`

Comment: OK I have successfully bring my external domain in azure. but when i open dealkar.pk it points to godaddy contents. But it should point to azure contents.

Comment: My domain DNS Manager contains a cname record with Host = `awverify`, points to = `awverify.dealkar1.azurewebsites.net`. When I try to add a cname record with Host = `dealkar.pk` and points to = `dealkar1.azurewebsites.net`. It says : `The specified CNAME already exists in the zone.`

Comment: Can you share all entries of your DNS zone? It might make things easier.

Comment: Please check here  https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipNzzH3OwSvli3v35TSMeqanBzXVUO4a_4EKc2Zm5160izcHX3kThUe3ZmwHCZvSAg/photo/AF1QipMHHuixVyeyzowJ5zfjgmQspW3XyL_xdYWMsm6B?key=ZGNRbzl5MkMxYk9TSktPUXVmNEotcjRMRGl1dHJR

Comment: My website main page is now pointing to azure contents but still it is fetching data from godaddy database. Its not fetching data from azure database.(PS: I have rechecked my connection strings! and I have added a record in domain manager with Ip given in bottom on azure portal in `Bring external domains`

Comment: My website main page again pointing to godaddy contents.`Update:` Nope sometimes it fetches azure contents and sometimes it fetches godaddy contents

Comment: The reason for this is that the site is still pointing to GoDaddy Because of your `@` A record configuration which is pointing to `182.50.151.83` which is your GoDaddy's IP address (http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/182.50.151.83). If you delete this record, then your other `@` A record will come into action. This other record (`13.67.56.225`) is the IP address of Azure (http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/13.67.56.225).

Comment: ok! now my website is pointing to azure contents. But IP's are not static. what if `13.67.56.225` got changed?

Comment: From this page: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/, `The IP address may change if you delete and recreate your web app, or change the web app mode back to free.`. My take is that if you don't do anything like this, your IP address won't change. If it changes, you would need to go back and update A records.

Comment: Thank you sir for your precious time. You helped me more than my expectation!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that things are working for you now :). Pleasure was all mine!